# adding a required rule to devextreme scheduler - Angular

Tags: angular, calendar, devexpress, devextreme

i'am using angular and devextreme scheduler's plugin to make an google calendar like app.
When i create an appointment, i've made a custom form. subject / Date / and a select box to select a person.
i force the required rules to my subject using this function :

Calendar.component.ts:

```
  onAppointmentFormCreated(data: any) {
    console.log(data)
      let form = data.form;
      form.itemOption("text","isRequired",true);
  }
```

I tryed to force a required method to my selectbox using the method i described. but on the devextreme scheduler's documentation i found nothing useful.
So i tryed to use Dx form validator method doing this :
 calendar.component.html

```
<dx-scheduler
    [showAllDayPanel]="false"
    [dataSource]="appointmentsData"
    appointmentTemplate="appointmentTemplate"
    [views]='["agenda","workWeek"]'
    startDateExpr="startDate"
    endDateExpr="endDate"
    currentView="workWeek"
    textExpr="text"
    [firstDayOfWeek]="1"
    [startDayHour]="9"
    [endDayHour]="18"
    width="100%"
    [height]="1100"
    (onAppointmentFormCreated)="onAppointmentFormCreated($event)"
    (onAppointmentAdding)="creatingAppointment($event)"
    (onAppointmentAdded)="createAppointment($event)"
    (onAppointmentUpdated)= "updatingAppointment($event)"
    (onAppointmentDeleted)= "deletingAppointment($event)">

    <dx-date-box [value] = "date" >
      <dxo-display-format  type="shortDateFR"></dxo-display-format>
    </dx-date-box>

    <div *dxTemplate="let appointment of 'appointmentTemplate'">
    <i>{{appointment.text}} -- </i>
    <b>{{appointment.ownerName}}</b>
    </div>

    <dxi-resource
        fieldExpr="ownerId"
        label="Personne"
        [dataSource]="personData">
        <dx-validator>
            <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Person is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
        </dx-validator> 
    </dxi-resource>

</dx-scheduler>
```

adding this to my calendar module:

```
import ....         DxValidatorModule,DxValidationSummaryModule
```

like i saw here : https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Validation/Overview/Angular/Light/ ( like country )

i would like to add a required validator function to my selectbox but i don't know how...
Need some help please.
Thanks very much

Comment: `I tryed to force a required method to my selectbox using the method i described` How did you try it? https://plnkr.co/edit/JckSs70CINzFiSW4ZW8q?p=preview

Comment: Ok, am just dumb, i didn't try ownerId on my form option...
Make an answer and i'll mark as answer. You'll have some reputation's points. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quess your method should work. Just make sure that you specified the correct `fieldName`:

```
form.itemOption('ownerId', 'isRequired', true);
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JckSs70CINzFiSW4ZW8q?p=preview)**